# Problem with SimpleDOM and sortedXPath

Tags: xml, sorting, xpath, simpledom

i have this XML structure:

```
<album _mngid="1">
  <contentxmlurl>alb_1.xml</contentxmlurl>
  <contentnumber>15</contentnumber>
  <thumb>
      <url>albthumbs/albth_1.jpg</url>
  </thumb>
</album>


  <album _mngid="2">
    <contentxmlurl>alb_2.xml</contentxmlurl>
    <contentnumber>35</contentnumber>
    <thumb>
      <url>albthumbs/albth_2.jpg</url>
    </thumb>
      </album>


  <album _mngid="3">
    <contentxmlurl>alb_3.xml</contentxmlurl>
    <contentnumber>3</contentnumber>
    <thumb>
      <url>albthumbs/albth_3.jpg</url>
    </thumb>
  </album>
```

I'd like to order di XML file by the evalue of  '_mngid' attribute, but i have a lot of problem.. :(

The best that i've tryed is:
foreach($xml->sortedXPath('collection/album','/@_mngid', SORT_DESC) as $album) {

but i obtain this order: 1,2,12,3,10,4,14,5,9,6,11,7,13,8,15 (in the XML file i have now 15 items).

Can u help me please to understand the right way?

Thanks very very much!
bye bye

Comment: There isn't a sort mechanism in XPath 1.0. So this question is only about the not standard `sortedXPath` method of your XPath engine. Retagging.

Comment: Hi,
excuse me but i don't understand well what i do.. :)
I must change the tag of my discussion? I must delete "xpathengines"? I use SimpleDOM and i must sorting the node of my xml file.. Please tell me exactly what i must do! Thanks very much! bye

Answer (score 0):

You are using `/@_mngid`, which corresponds to the root node. If you want to select the current node's attribute, use `@_mngid`. For instance:

```
foreach($xml->sortedXPath('collection/album','@_mngid', SORT_DESC) as $album) {
```